# NG-Bootstrap Navbar- animated hamburger animation

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, css-animations, ng-bootstrap

I've seen a lot of tutorials how to get an animated hamburger animation on the navbar done. Unfortunately nothing works when I'm using ng-bootstrap and Angular. **The Navbar does colapse indeed**, but with no animation and transforming into a 'x'. Maybe some of you can help.

### HTML

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarGrey"
          aria-controls="navbarGrey" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">

    <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </button>
```

### scss

```
// Navbar styling

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: ease all .2s;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar + .icon-bar {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

//Animation part   <== does not work here

.navbar-toggler .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

.navbar-toggler .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

### EDIT

created a [stackblitz-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpsfsb) for the navbar.

Comment: Can you show your code in stackblitz

Comment: Updated my question - stackblitz example created.^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you animated styles, you want to use `.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="false"]` for when it is expanded and you want the "X" (rather than `.navbar-toggler`), and `.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"]` for when it is collapsed (rather than `.navbar-toggler.collapsed`) and you want the hamburger. The full CSS for the animation is:

```
// Animation part
.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="false"] .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="false"] .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="false"] .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

ng-bootstrap seems to change the `aria-expanded` attribute when the navbar is expanded/collapsed rather than adding/remove the the `collapsed` CSS class.

Please see this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aprhds?file=src/app/app.component.scss) for a demo

Comment: U saved me. Thanks a lot!